# How to add variying markers to a map when accessing external JSON data asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, leaflet, mapbox

I have the following markercollection.json file with several geographical objects in an array called `features`.

```
{
    "features":
    [
        {
            "name": "Point A",
            "address": {
                "street": "228 Park Ave S",
                "zipcode": "10003",
                "city": "New York"
            },
            "description": "Sample description for point A",
            "iconFile": "icon-marker-iconsample-a.png",
            "filterPrimary": "hotel",
            "year": "2014"
        },
        {
            "name": "Point B",
            "address": {
                "street": "542 W. 27th Street",
                "zipcode": "10001",
                "city": "New York"
            },
            "description": "Sample description for point B",
            "iconFile": "icon-marker-iconsample-b.png",
            "filterPrimary": "pub",
            "year": "2015"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the leaflet JavaScript library to put corresponding markers on a map. Since I do not have the longitudes and latitudes I have pass the object's `address` to a geocoding service. For this I am currently using mapbox, but I also tried with OSM nominatim. Both work as expected.

The [mapbox geocoding API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-mapbox-geocoder/) expects a callback function to be passed to do something with the resulting data (i.e. longitude and latitude).

So far I have worked out how to pass the geo-objects to the geocoder and have my `addMarkers` callback function add the corresponding markers to my map. In addition to this I would also like to have my markers have different icons depending on the `iconFile` value in the original JSON file.

I haven't been able to figure out where to build and subsequently add my customized markers. I tried building the marker icon for every loop but that leaves me with the same icon for all markers (see my screenshot).

[image: Result of console.log variable value when simply assigning the icon file string value within the loop and accessing it within the callback function]

I assume this is because the loop has finished before my `addMarkers` function is triggered, so the value of `sIconFile` is that of the last loop iteration.

**Do I have to chain another callback, and if so, what's the best way to do this?**

```
        // Pass Mapbox access token and set initial map view
        L.mapbox.accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;
        var myMap = L.mapbox.map('map','mapbox.streets').setView([40.730610, -73.935242], 13);

        // 
        var promise = $.getJSON('data/markercollection.json')
            .then(function(data) {

                /**
                 * Iterate through fetched data and do something...
                 */
                for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {

                    // Build address string for passing to geocoder
                    var sAddress = data.features[i].address.street + ', ' + data.features[i].address.zipcode + ', ' + data.features[i].address.city;

                    // Icon file string variable
                    var sIconFile = data.features[i].iconFile;

                    /**
                     * Query Mapbox geocoder with address string
                     * and pass reply to addMakers function as per
                     * mapbox geocoder API
                     */
                    L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places').query(sAddress, addMarkers);

                    // Add markers to geocoded latitudes and longitudes to map 
                    function addMarkers(err, geocoderCallbackData) {
                        console.log(sIconFile); // accessing the variable here does not work :(
                        L.marker(geocoderCallbackData.latlng).addTo(myMap);
                    }
                }

            // Basic error-handling
            }, function() {
                console.log('An error has occured!');
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looping through `data.features` with `forEach(fn)` instead of a `for(...)` loop, you will benefit from the local scope afforded by `fn`.

Therefore :

```
data.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    var sAddress = feature.address.street + ', ' + feature.address.zipcode + ', ' + feature.address.city;
    var sIconFile = feature.iconFile;
    L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places').query(sAddress, addMarkers);
    function addMarkers(err, geocoderCallbackData) {
        console.log(sIconFile);
        L.marker(geocoderCallbackData.latlng).addTo(myMap);
    }
});
```